# R delete Dataframe columns with specific rows conditions

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, na, is-empty

I have a dataframe with empty and NA values, like that:

```
> DF_datos
 
   V1  V2  V3  V4  V5 V6 
3 aaa aaa             NA
4  bb  bb  70  80     NA
5  cc  cc  80  80     NA
6 ddd ddd             NA
```

I would like to delete all columns that contains an empty or NA value on its second or third row, without a loop over the dataframe. With subset function or something similar...
The result I want would be:

```
> DF_datos
 
   V1  V2  V3  V4 
3 aaa aaa           
4  bb  bb  70  80   
5  cc  cc  80  80    
6 ddd ddd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `tidyverse` with `select` from `dplyr`.  In `select`, specify the logical expression in `where` to check if there are `any` non-NA (`!is.na(.)`) and `any` non-blank (`nzchar`) elements in the column to be selected

```
library(dplyr)
DF_datos %>%
      select(where(~ any(!is.na(.))&any(nzchar(.))))
```

-output

```
#   V1  V2 V3 V4
#3 aaa aaa      
#4  bb  bb 70 80
#5  cc  cc 80 80
#6 ddd ddd
```

If we need to only check the 2nd or 3rd row

```
DF_datos %>%
  slice(2:3) %>% 
  select(where(~ any(!is.na(.))&any(nzchar(.)))) %>% 
  names %>% 
  select(DF_datos, .)
```

---

Or with `Filter` from `base R` (`R 4.1.0`) using the same logic

```
Filter(\(x) any(!is.na(x)) & any(nzchar(x)), DF_datos)
```

-output

```
#   V1  V2 V3 V4
#3 aaa aaa      
#4  bb  bb 70 80
#5  cc  cc 80 80
#6 ddd ddd
```

Or for rows 2 and 3

```
Filter(\(x) any(!is.na(x)) & any(nzchar(x)), DF_datos[2:3,]) |>
      names() |>
      {\(x) subset(DF_datos, select = x)}()
```

Or use `sum` instead of `any` by checking if the `sum` of the compound logical expression is greater than 0

```
Filter(\(x) sum(!is.na(x) & nzchar(x)) > 0, DF_datos)
```

In earlier `R` versions use

```
Filter(function(x) any(!is.na(x)) & any(nzchar(x)), DF_datos)
```

NOTE: All of the above options are efficient as this loops over the columns and is memory efficient as this won't apply the expression on the whole dataset

#### Update

Based on the comments, the OP wanted to delete columns if there are any NA or blank in rows 2 or 3.

```
DF_datos$V6 <- c(NA, NA, 80, NA)

DF_datos %>%
  slice(2:3) %>% 
  select(where(~ all(!is.na(.)) & all(nzchar(.)))) %>% names %>% 
  select(DF_datos, .)
```

-output

```
  V1  V2 V3 V4
3 aaa aaa      
4  bb  bb 70 80
5  cc  cc 80 80
6 ddd ddd
```

---

Or using `Filter`

```
Filter(\(x) all(!is.na(x)) & all(nzchar(x)), DF_datos[2:3,]) |>
       names() |>
       {\(x) subset(DF_datos, select = x)}()
#   V1  V2 V3 V4
#3 aaa aaa      
#4  bb  bb 70 80
#5  cc  cc 80 80
#6 ddd ddd
```

#### data

```
DF_datos <- structure(list(V1 = c("aaa", "bb", "cc", "ddd"), V2 = c("aaa", 
"bb", "cc", "ddd"), V3 = c("", "70", "80", ""), V4 = c("", "80", 
"80", ""), V5 = c("", "", "", ""), V6 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c("3", 
"4", "5", "6"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Thanks, it work for my specific example, but not It was I was looking for. I tried with a diferent dataframe and don't work. If there is any NA or empty value on the second o third row, delete the column of that position.

Comment: @Mantanamm your logic should be met with `DF_datos %>% slice(2:3) %>%  select(where(~ any(!is.na(.))&any(nzchar(.)))) %>% names %>% select(DF_datos, .)`

Comment: Yes, totally agree. Maybe my initial example is not enough clear

Comment: @Mantanamm i updated the post and it works with your example for rows 2 and 3.  Pleae check my update

Comment: Hmm still not what i looking for. I changed the initial v6 example for: V6 = c(NA, NA, 80, NA)). Column v6 should be deleted due to the NA on second row, and it is not deleted. My idea is :If there is any na OR empty value on the second OR third row, delete the column of that position. (Maybe my idea without a loop is not posible hahah). Thanks

Comment: @Mantanamm Can you update your post with a `dput(yourexample)` to get the structure orrect

Comment: @Mantanamm I updated the post.  I hope this works.  If it works, please consider to accept solution.

Comment: I tested diferent cases and It works, thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

Using `colSums` -

```
DF_datos[colSums(is.na(DF_datos) | DF_datos == '') != nrow(DF_datos)]

#   V1  V2 V3 V4
#3 aaa aaa      
#4  bb  bb 70 80
#5  cc  cc 80 80
#6 ddd ddd
```

Another way to write this would be -

```
DF_datos[colSums(!is.na(DF_datos) & DF_datos != '') != 0]
```